# Installing mongodb error : require openssl

Tags: mongodb, openssl, redhat

Hello I'm newer using mongodb, and I'm following step Installing mongodb from web [Installing mongodb enterprise on red hat](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-enterprise-on-red-hat/)

I'm use command:

```
sudo yum install -y mongodb-enterprise
```

and The terminal print:

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-managerThis system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.Repository 'repository_url': Error parsing config: Error parsing "baseurl = 'repository_url'": URL must be http, ftp, file or https not ""Setting up Install ProcessResolving Dependencies--> Running transaction check---> Package mongodb-enterprise.x86_64 0:3.4.11-1.el6 will be installed--> Processing Dependency: mongodb-enterprise-tools = 3.4.11 for package: mongodb-enterprise-3.4.11-1.el6.x86_64--> Processing Dependency: mongodb-enterprise-shell = 3.4.11 for package: mongodb-enterprise-3.4.11-1.el6.x86_64--> Processing Dependency: mongodb-enterprise-server = 3.4.11 for package: mongodb-enterprise-3.4.11-1.el6.x86_64--> Processing Dependency: mongodb-enterprise-mongos = 3.4.11 for package: mongodb-enterprise-3.4.11-1.el6.x86_64--> Running transaction check---> Package mongodb-enterprise-mongos.x86_64 0:3.4.11-1.el6 will be installed---> Package mongodb-enterprise-server.x86_64 0:3.4.11-1.el6 will be installed--> Processing Dependency: openssl >= 1.0.1 for package: mongodb-enterprise-server-3.4.11-1.el6.x86_64---> Package mongodb-enterprise-shell.x86_64 0:3.4.11-1.el6 will be installed--> Processing Dependency: openssl >= 1.0.1 for package: mongodb-enterprise-shell-3.4.11-1.el6.x86_64---> Package mongodb-enterprise-tools.x86_64 0:3.4.11-1.el6 will be installed--> Processing Dependency: openssl >= 1.0.1 for package: mongodb-enterprise-tools-3.4.11-1.el6.x86_64--> Finished Dependency ResolutionError: Package: mongodb-enterprise-server-3.4.11-1.el6.x86_64 (mongodb-enterprise)           Requires: openssl >= 1.0.1           Installed: openssl-1.0.0-27.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201301301459.x86_64/6.4)               openssl = 1.0.0-27.el6Error: Package: mongodb-enterprise-tools-3.4.11-1.el6.x86_64 (mongodb-enterprise)           Requires: openssl >= 1.0.1           Installed: openssl-1.0.0-27.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201301301459.x86_64/6.4)               openssl = 1.0.0-27.el6Error: Package: mongodb-enterprise-shell-3.4.11-1.el6.x86_64 (mongodb-enterprise)           Requires: openssl >= 1.0.1           Installed: openssl-1.0.0-27.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201301301459.x86_64/6.4)               openssl = 1.0.0-27.el6 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

But I'm already installed openssl:
Command

```
openssl version
```

print:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
```

As you see I'm already installed openssl. So What is wrong with my step.

Comment: am'I install openssl right?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww thankU for comment